# Joining two csv files in bash

Tags: bash, join, merge

I have to `join` two files by values in one column. I need to use unix `bash`.

My first file looks like this:

```
user_id, song_id, timestamp
00001638d6189236866af9bbf309ae6c2347ffdc,SOBBMDR12A8C13253B,1203083335
00001638d6189236866af9bbf309ae6c2347ffdc,SOBXALG12A8C13C108,984663773
00001cf0dce3fb22b0df0f3a1d9cd21e38385372,SODDNQT12A6D4F5F7E,1275071044
00001cf0dce3fb22b0df0f3a1d9cd21e38385372,SODDNQT12A6D4F5F7E,1097509573
```

Second file:

```
user_id, natural_key
00000b722001882066dff9d2da8a775658053ea0,6944471
00001638d6189236866af9bbf309ae6c2347ffdc,19309784
0000175652312d12576d9e6b84f600caa24c4715,10435505
00001cf0dce3fb22b0df0f3a1d9cd21e38385372,5232769
```

Of course both files have many more rows. I would like to `join` both files by first column (*user_id*) and get this result:

```
natural_key, song_id, timestamp
19309784,SOBBMDR12A8C13253B,1203083335
19309784,SOBXALG12A8C13C108,984663773
5232769,SODDNQT12A6D4F5F7E,1275071044
5232769,SODDNQT12A6D4F5F7E,1097509573
```

I tried to do something with `join` and `awk` but to no avail. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

With GNU join, sed, sort and bash:

```
echo "natural_key, song_id, timestamp"
join -t, <(sed '1d' file1 |sort -t, -k1,1) <(sed '1d' file2 | sort -t, -k1,1) -o 2.2,1.2,1.3
```

Output:

```
natural_key, song_id, timestamp
19309784,SOBBMDR12A8C13253B,1203083335
19309784,SOBXALG12A8C13C108,984663773
5232769,SODDNQT12A6D4F5F7E,1097509573
5232769,SODDNQT12A6D4F5F7E,1275071044
```

Comment: what version of `join` are you using? This produces error for me: `$ join -t, <(sed '1d' file1 |sort -t, -k1,1) <(sed '1d' file2 | sort -t, -k1,1) -o 2.2,1.2,1.3
usage: join [-a fileno | -v fileno ] [-e string] [-1 field] [-2 field]
            [-o list] [-t char] file1 file2`

Comment: When I wrote the answer, I used a version from Ubuntu 11.04. I just did it successfully with join version 8.25 from GNU coreutils (Ubuntu 16.04.3).

Comment: Thanks for super speed answer. I'm on Unix, `man join` just brings up a BSD General Commands Manual with no version number but dated July 5, 2004. Presume my OSX is not utd!

Comment: @kungfujam: I have updated my answer to take your feedback into account.

Answer (score 1):

This one in GNU awk (regex `FS`). That header spacing in your example I'm just going to ignore:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=", ?";OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{print a[$1],$2,$3}' file2 file1
natural_key,song_id,timestamp
19309784,SOBBMDR12A8C13253B,1203083335
19309784,SOBXALG12A8C13C108,984663773
5232769,SODDNQT12A6D4F5F7E,1275071044
5232769,SODDNQT12A6D4F5F7E,1097509573
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN   { FS=", ?"; OFS="," }    # set the delimiters
NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next }       # hash the first file in paramaters 
$1 in a { print a[$1], $2, $3 }  # if key is found in hash, output
' file2 file1                    # mind the order
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`mlr`](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) util:

```
mlr --csvlite  join -j user_id -f f1.csv \
         then  cut -o -f ' natural_key',' song_id',' timestamp' f2.csv
```

Output:

```
 natural_key, song_id, timestamp
19309784,SOBBMDR12A8C13253B,1203083335
19309784,SOBXALG12A8C13C108,984663773
5232769,SODDNQT12A6D4F5F7E,1275071044
5232769,SODDNQT12A6D4F5F7E,1097509573
```

Note the leading spaces in the headers.  These are left intact here because:

1. Most of the source data headers have leading spaces, but the data does not.
2. The leading spaces, if unquoted, will fail with most *CSV* oriented utils.

Comment: Compare your first column with tech2nick‘s desired first column.

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks -- the OP's typos and phrasing of "*get result like this*", led me to infer wrongly that the OP's desired output example wasn't meaningful.  Answer modified, as well as some OP ambiguities.